# A warning "WARNING: linker: "vgpreload_core-arm64-linux.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x421" came when executing Valgrind in Android

Tags: android, valgrind, android-8.1-oreo, memcheck

I have tried to run Valgrind MemCheck in Android Orea 8.1 using adb shell. But initially it gave many errors, I have hacked into it till this point. Now am getting this error.

Valgrind has been deprecated from AOSP. But I needed to use memcheck on my Android Services and some Native Services.

The hack I did to make it work till now is as follow,
1. Modified the library location from /system/lib64/valgrind to /system/lib64 in Android.mk file.
2. Modified the permission of memcheck-arm64-linux to 777.

Now, I have this Warning and some errors in linker64.

```
==4622== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4622== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4622== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4622== Command: /system/bin/ValgrindProgram
==4622== 
WARNING: linker: "/system/lib64/vgpreload_core-arm64-linux.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x421
WARNING: linker: "/system/lib64/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so" has unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x421
==4622== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4622==    at 0x409D684: __dl_strcpy (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401D89F: __dl__ZN14CachedProperty8CallbackEPvPKcS2_j (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x40A2217: __dl___system_property_read_callback (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E457: __dl__ZL12should_tracev (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E0EB: __dl__Z18bionic_trace_beginPKc (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020AC3: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401CA17: __dl___linker_init (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622== 
==4622== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4622==    at 0x409D6AC: __dl_strcpy (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401D89F: __dl__ZN14CachedProperty8CallbackEPvPKcS2_j (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x40A2217: __dl___system_property_read_callback (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E457: __dl__ZL12should_tracev (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E0EB: __dl__Z18bionic_trace_beginPKc (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020AC3: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401CA17: __dl___linker_init (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622== 
==4622== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4622==    at 0x409D6B8: __dl_strcpy (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401D89F: __dl__ZN14CachedProperty8CallbackEPvPKcS2_j (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x40A2217: __dl___system_property_read_callback (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E457: __dl__ZL12should_tracev (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E0EB: __dl__Z18bionic_trace_beginPKc (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020AC3: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401CA17: __dl___linker_init (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622== 
==4622== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4622==    at 0x409D6C4: __dl_strcpy (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401D89F: __dl__ZN14CachedProperty8CallbackEPvPKcS2_j (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x40A2217: __dl___system_property_read_callback (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E457: __dl__ZL12should_tracev (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E0EB: __dl__Z18bionic_trace_beginPKc (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020AC3: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401CA17: __dl___linker_init (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622== 
==4622== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4622==    at 0x409D6D0: __dl_strcpy (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401D89F: __dl__ZN14CachedProperty8CallbackEPvPKcS2_j (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x40A2217: __dl___system_property_read_callback (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E457: __dl__ZL12should_tracev (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x409E0EB: __dl__Z18bionic_trace_beginPKc (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020AC3: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401CA17: __dl___linker_init (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622== 
==4622== Source and destination overlap in memcpy(0x4d53ae8, 0x4d53ae8, 104)
==4622==    at 0x4AE8FB8: memcpy (in /system/lib64/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
==4622==    by 0x4D26167: je_malloc_tsd_boot0 (in /system/lib64/libc.so)
==4622==    by 0x4D1C433: jemalloc_constructor (in /system/lib64/libc.so)
==4622==    by 0x40208FF: __dl__ZL10call_arrayIPFviPPcS1_EEvPKcPT_mbS5_ (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020B2B: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x4020A23: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x401CA17: __dl___linker_init (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x40230E7: _start (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x40230E7: _start (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622==    by 0x40230E7: _start (in /system/bin/linker64)
==4622== 
==4622== 
==4622== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4622==     in use at exit: 9,410 bytes in 250 blocks
==4622==   total heap usage: 428 allocs, 178 frees, 25,671 bytes allocated
==4622== 
==4622== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4622==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4622==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4622==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4622==    still reachable: 9,410 bytes in 250 blocks
==4622==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4622== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4622== 
==4622== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4622== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==4622== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: did you solve it?